# Which is the best glass for shielding against radiations and impacts?

Tags: shielding

Which glass should be used for overcoming radiation and orbital debris?

I have seen about monolithic glass and acrylic glass, which can be used for this purpose.

Are there any others type which can work more effectively?

Comment: Please write a clearer question. Use glass *where*? How long will it be exposed? What surface area(s)?

Comment: is this for a spacecraft or for a dome on mars/moon,what type of radiation does it need to stop ir-uv-xray-gamma.